# iOS No visible @interface for 'ViewController' declares the selector addGestureRecognizer error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm trying to add the gesture recognizer to the main view but I'm getting this error:

No visible @interface for 'ViewController' declares the selector addGestureRecognizer error

on this line:

```
 [self addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self.view action:@selector(isTapped:)]];
```

any of you knows why of the error or how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

addGestureRecognizer is a method on UIView, not UIViewController.

Try

```
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(isTapped:)]];
```

Comment: it works but when I tap the view I'm getting this error: -[UIView isTapped:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa1a7010

Comment: Your target should just be `self`

Comment: @HelenaM You need to implement the `isTapped:` method in your view controller. Please read the documentation for `UIGestureRecognizer`.